# Static member modification in const member function in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on linked-list but can't modify the value of current pointer in const function "void Print() const"

In the function Print I want to do **"current= head"** & then increment like **"current=current->link"** but can't do so, bcz it is showing that

**"error C3490: 'current' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object   e:\Cpp\projects\data structure ass-1\data structure ass-1\source.cpp    83  1   Data Structure Ass-1
"**

```
#include<iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *link;
};    

class List
{
    node *head,*current,*last;
public:
    List();
//  List(const List&);
//  ~List();

void print() const;

};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List List1;
}

void List::print() const
{
     current=head;   //here is my error
     current=current->link;
}

List::List():current(head)
{

}
```

Comment: I think you've got some code in your whitespace/comments there! ;) But in all seriousness, please compact this example a little

Comment: You can make the current a `mutable` member to make it modifiable in `const` functions.

Comment: Or instead of using `current` as member, you can make a temporary local variable of type `node*` in `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `current` as a variable local to method print.  If you are using `current` as a member variable for other purposes, the local variable will shadow it.  If you are not using `current` as a member variable, then you can just delete it.

Answer (score 4):

If a member function of a class is declared as `const`:

```
void print() const;
```

it means, that this function cannot modify the data members of its class. In your case  variables:

```
node *head,*current,*last;
```

cannot be modified in the body of `print()`. Thus you cannot change addresses these pointers point to. A way round this problem is to define a local variable `temp` in your `print()` function. Such a variable can be modified and do the same job as `current` was supposed to do:

```
void List::print() const
{
    node *temp;     
    temp=head;   
    temp=temp->link;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a `const` member function the `this` pointer becomes `const` inside the `const` function when that is called for an object.

Meaning the `const` member function prevents any direct or in-direct modification of the data members of class.

Direct implies like the one you're doing in your program(modifying the data members directly in the `const` member function which is violating the purpose of it). It is ok to do any operations involving data members unless you're not modifying them. Also, you can call other `const` member functions inside a `const` member function.

And Indirect means you can't even call other `non-const` member functions of the class because they might modify the data members.

Usually `const` member functions are used when you just want to get/ read the values. Hence, in your case you shouldn't use a `const` member function.

Also, you can call `non-const` and `const` member functions for a `non-const` object.

Comment: The thing is, he can just make a local "current" pointer in his print function to use when traversing the list, rather than making it non-const. Const correctness is a good thing! Now if only we could teach people to stop using that atrocity "using namespace std;" ...

Comment: Yes, even I feel the same, but  the name of the function and its functionality are different in this case, `print` isn't actually printing anything.

Comment: print was for printing but for print we need to traversing the current by "current=current->link", Is there any other method to print all nodes of linked-list?

Comment: Oh, then. You can do as suggested by others, as by George in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the print() function as const. This means that the function does not modify the member variables of the class yet that is the first thing you do in the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `node *head,*current,*last;` to `mutable node *head,*current,*last;`

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what's happening - when you say `List::print() const`, you're promising not to modify any of the members of your list. But then you go and try to modify `current`.

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, but perhaps `current` shouldn't be a member variable, and should be local to `List::print()`. Or perhaps `List::print()` shouldn't be const. You could also make `current` mutable, but that is nearly always bad practice.